# Join in GUI not the same as ArcPy join

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1

I'm trying to join up some data so I can make some rasters. I am doing this in Python but when I create the [join in Python](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000064000000) in results in an empty attribute table for my shapefile. The columns from both the shapefile and the view I am using in the join are in the shapefile after the join and my view shows up as a joined table in `Joins and Relates` but there are no data at all.

My Python is:

```
arcpy.AddJoin_management("Area1_wellspiezometers", "LocId_Calc", "_107062_1_1999", "LocationName")
```

Where

- Area1_wellspiezometers is a shapefile
- LocId_Calc is an field in Area1_wellspiezometers
- `_107062_1_1999` is a view created with `arcpy.MakeTableView_management` from a table in an MDB.
- `LocationName` is a field in `_107062_1_1999`

Alternatively when I do this through the GUI I right click on `Area1_wellspiezometers` > Joins and Relates > Join... and enter my info as such:

[image]

This makes the join as expected and everything is dandy.

What is the difference between these two methods and how can I make the Python do what the GUI is doing?

Comment: Pretty sure the reason is you're trying to operate directly on the shapefile. If you read the first line of the help file you linked to, it states 'where layer is a **feature layer**'. And if you look at all the examples further down, note they all use `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management` prior to the join function.

Comment: @ChrisW If i make a FeatureLayer based on the shapefile first and join to that instead it is the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I needed to save my Table View to disk in order for it to be usable by a join. `CopyRows_management` was the missing link.

```
arcpy.MakeTableView_management(outGdb + "\myTable", viewName, sqlFilterForView ,outGdb)
arcpy.CopyRows_management(viewName, saveViewPath)
arcpy.AddJoin_management( shapeLayer  , joinField,  savedViewName  , joinField,"KEEP_COMMON")
```

Other suggestions like making my view a spatial layer by using `arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management` were not successful.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why it would work in the GUI - but according to [the docs under](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//005s0000002p000000#GUID-ECEE9408-A8A8-4C3F-9172-E88657ABC289) 'Reasons joining tables may fail' - it does list "avoid starting field names with a number or an underscore" - and has similar warnings against the feature name as well.

Comment: If I rename my view `V107062_1_1999` I get the same results

Comment: Shorter names of datasets help, especially with shapefiles

Comment: is the MDB that the table resides a GDB? or a standard MS MDB?

Comment: @fluidmotion the mdb is a Personal GeoDatabase I created with ArcCatalog and pulled in a table from Excel (also from Catalog) using the import button on the context menu.

Comment: @FelixIP Do you know how short is short enough?

Comment: Under 10 characters, no 'exotic' characters, e.g. white spaces. abcdefg_12.dbf is ok. Try search for shapefile naming.